# Functional graphs and injective graphs

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Definition:

Let $G$ be a graph. $G$ is a functional graph if and only if $(x_1,y_1) \in G$ and $(x_1,y_2) \in G$ implies $y_1=y_2$.

Problem statement, as written:

Let $G$ be a functional graph. Prove that $G$ is injective if and only if for arbitrary graphs $J$ and $H$, $G \circ (H \cap J)$ $=$ $(G \circ H) \cap (G \circ J)$.

I am concerned with the direction of the biconditional proving that $G$ is injective. I have completed a proof which seems consistent to me, but does not utilize the premise of $G$ being a functional graph anywhere in the argument (including the other direction of the biconditional). Is it simply necessary, a priori, for a graph to be a functional graph in order for it to be considered injective?

I can post my proof if needed, but here is the gist: I suppose the antecedent (assume for arbitrary graphs $J,H$ that the equality written above holds). Then I proceed via contradiction, supposing (to the contrary) $G$ is not injective. This brings into existence two elements (ordered pairs) of $G$ with unequal first elements, but equal second elements. From here, I construct $J,H$ such that I may use the equality given above to show that the unequal first elements, in fact, are equal- a contradiction.

*Nowhere do I use the fact that $G$ is a functional graph. For some reason, this isn’t sitting well. Is my conjecture above true about graphs unable to be considered injective if they are not first classified as functional?

Comment: A functional graph is a collection of disconnected edges.  How is the composition of two graphs defined?

Comment: Suppose $G,H$ are graphs. Let $G \circ H$ $=$ ${(x,z) | (x,y) \in H$ and $(y,z) \in G$ for some $y}$.

Comment: What a weird comment.

Comment: It seems you can define a more general injective property for arbitrary graphs (without them satisfying the functional property): Let $G$ be an arbitrary graph. $G$ is injective if and only if $\forall (a,b),(c,d)\in G$, if $b=d$, then $a=c$. I'm guessing the author introduced the functional graph concept in order to preserve the familiar conception of"injective," even though either route leads to, essentially, the same proof and outcome.

Comment: Graphs, relations and functions are three different things and trying to use the concepts of one of those for any of the others is a futile exercise of intellectual gibbering, useless busywork.  Even the concept of composition of relations and of functions are defined differently unless it is important to make composition obnoxious, usually for relations.  Have they dreamed up a useful composition of graphs?